# How do I use PyMock and Nose with Django models?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, nose

I'm trying to do TDD with PyMock, but I keep getting error when I use Nose and execute core.py from command line:

"ERROR: Failure: ImportError (Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJA
NGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.)"

If I remove "from cms.models import Entry" from the unit test module I created, everything works fine, but I need to mock functionality in django module cms.models.Entry that I created.

What am I doing wrong? Can this be done?

Comment: Is it too obvious to ask if you have DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE defined?

Comment: I +1 this b/c it pointed me in the right direction. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **do** need `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` defined in order to run `core.py` -- why don't you just `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=whatever` in your bash session before starting nose?

Comment: Got it working doing just that with one small difference:
I'm using Windows Vista x64 (don't know how much difference that makes?) so I ran:
"Set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myblog.settings" in at the command line.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @mkelley33, you're welcome -- sure, ways to set environment variables differ by OS (and actually by shell within a single OS;-).