# django test client trouble

Tags: python, django

I've got a problem... we're writing project using django, and i'm trying to use django.test.client with nose test-framework for tests.

Our code is like this:

```
from simplejson import loads
from urlparse import urljoin

from django.test.client import Client

TEST_URL = "http://smakly.localhost:9090/"

def test_register():

    cln = Client()

    ref_data = {"email": "unique@mail.com", "name": "Василий", "website": "http://hot.bear.com", "xhr": "true"}

    print urljoin(TEST_URL, "/accounts/register/")
    response = loads(cln.post(urljoin(TEST_URL, "/accounts/register/"), ref_data))

    print response["message"]
```

and in nose output I catch:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/psih/work/svn/smakly/eggs/nose-0.11.1-py2.6.egg/nose/case.py", line 183, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/psih/work/svn/smakly/src/smakly.tests/smakly/tests/frontend/test_profile.py", line 25, in test_register
    response = loads(cln.post(urljoin(TEST_URL, "/accounts/register/"), ref_data))
  File "/home/psih/work/svn/smakly/parts/django/django/test/client.py", line 313, in post
    response = self.request(**r)
  File "/home/psih/work/svn/smakly/parts/django/django/test/client.py", line 225, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/home/psih/work/svn/smakly/parts/django/django/test/client.py", line 69, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/psih/work/svn/smakly/parts/django/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 78, in get_response
    urlconf = getattr(request, "urlconf", settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
  File "/home/psih/work/svn/smakly/parts/django/django/utils/functional.py", line 273, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

My settings.py file does have this attribute.

If I get the data from the server with standard `urllib2.urllopen().read()` it works in the proper way.

Any ideas how I can solve this case?

Comment: Go take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240067/why-does-nose-not-see-any-of-my-environmental-variables or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484293/how-do-i-use-pymock-and-nose-with-django-models

Comment: Gabriel, thanx, these solutions looks quite clear.
before asking question, i was trying to add to the beginning of test file string:
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "smakly.frontend.settings"
but still no help. after reading your links, i exported this variable from bash - it helps. And logical question - how can i make such export from python test-file?

Comment: had the same problem, i just delete settings.pyc file and restart server and error was gone... strange stuff;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably want django-nose if you want to use nose.

http://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose

I would recommend using the TestCase class

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/

http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/test_client/

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self-promotion: exactly for those reasons I made test library that enables you to test application with urllib2.

Docs are there: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-sane-testing/en/latest/

Example of what You might want to do is, for example, [in django-http-digest-tests](https://github.com/Almad/django-http-digest/blob/master/testproject/tests/test_simple_digest.py#L35%20%22in%20django-http-digest%22%20tests.)